# Pytorch: TypeError: list is not a Module subclass

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

I want to extract some layers from a model, so I write

```py
nn.Sequential(list(model.children())[:7])
```

but get error: list is not a Moudule subclass. I know I should write

```py
nn.Sequential(*list(model.children)[:7])
```

but why I must add the * ???
If I just wanna to get the [] including the layers, I must write

```py
layer = list(model.children())[:7]
but not
layer = *list(model.children())[:7]
```

In this situation, the * does not work and get error

```py
    layer = *list(model_ft.children())[:3]
           ^
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
```

Why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list(model.children())[:7]` returns a list, but the input of `nn.Sequential()` requires the modules to be an OrderedDict or to be added directly, not in a python list.

> [`nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html) Modules will be added to it in the order they are passed in the constructor. Alternatively, an OrderedDict of modules can be passed in.

```py
# nn.Sequential(list(model.children)[:3]) means, which is wrong
nn.Sequential([Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3)),
ReLU(inplace=True),
MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)])

# nn.Sequential(*list(model.children)[:3]) mean
nn.Sequential(Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3)),
ReLU(inplace=True),
MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False))
```

That's why you need to unpack the list using `*`. It can only be used inside a function, hence, it doesn't work in your last case. Read [* in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2921847/6210807)

Comment: @qichengwang you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/446268) the answer by clicking the "correct" sign.

Comment: Of course i will